# Why need to restrict data inserts that do not specify edge types？

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```cpp
neo4j@neo4j> create (v:player)-[]->();
Exactly one relationship type must be specified for CREATE. Did you forget to prefix your relationship type with a ':'? (line 2, column 18 (offset: 18))
"create (v:player)-[]->();"
```

I think this is also useful for queries like `MATCH p=(v:player)-[]->() RETURN p`, so why limit it?
Actually, WHEN I was watching cypher, I was a little confused about why to proposed the concept of `relationship type` instead of the concept of `Edge label`.
Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relationship type and edge label are identical concepts. Each relationship needs exactly a single type or label to be defined when you import the graph. You can always use a generic edge label like `RELATIONSHIP` if you don't have a specific edge label in mind.

```
create (v:player)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->(:player);
```

This is how the property graph model is defined in Neo4j. However, you can always match relationships and disregard the relationship type as in your example:

```
MATCH p=(v:player)-[]->() RETURN p
```

For more details on modelling relationships in Neo4j, check the following blog post: https://medium.com/neo4j/graph-data-modeling-all-about-relationships-5060e46820ce

Comment: I can create a node without label, but can not create an edge without label.   

In some cases I only know that these entities are connected, but I don't know or care what the connection is.

Comment: ```neo4j@neo4j> create (v);   
0 rows available after 54 ms, consumed after another 0 ms   
Added 1 nodes   
neo4j@neo4j> create (v)-[]->();   
Exactly one relationship type must be specified for CREATE.   
```

Comment: Yes, when you dont care about relationship type, just use a generic default type. Creating nodes without a label is bad practice, use a default label for nodes as well